# Placeholder and a default value shown at the same time

Tags: html, input, default-value, placeholder

How can I show the default value of my input field and the placeholder to give my users a hint on what the range of numbers he should input is?

this is my code

```html
<input class="inputs len_md" placeholder="0~65535" value="0" required>
```

what i need is to show the placeholder on the right part of the input field. How can I possibly do that? Im using html and angularjs

Comment: can you more specific? you want to show placeholder and value at a time ?else you want to show value on your `input `right side

Comment: either you set placeholder or you set the value both is not possible

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to use both in a input form. Because placeholder inform to user for some example but value is for to use set default value. So, in the web page there is use just value not placeholder. If you thinking to valid of form like between some numbers like 0-30, 7-100 etc. you need to use javascript or jquery.